# Riemann Integral Tagged Partition Independence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the limit exists for some partitioning and sampling scheme.

How to prove the limit exists, and is the same limit, for all partitioning, sampling schemes?

I.e. The limit is independent of "tagged partition" choice.

(Not homework - just curious)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if a function is Riemann integrable, then the upper and lower Riemann sums converge to the same value as the mesh of an arbitrary partition becomes arbitrarily small. Since these are upper and lower bounds the Riemann sum of every possible tagged partition over $[a,b]$, the squeeze theorem implies that they all must converge to $I$ as required.

Comment: This works for continuous functions. If the function has a finite number of discontinuities, the contributions of the elements that fall along the discontinuities become negligible as the mesh becomes small.

Comment: @fredq I thought the Riemann integral existed iff the upper and lower sums converged to the same value, no? So it should still hold not only for continuous functions but for discontinuous functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix both the partitioning scheme as well as sampling scheme. One of them has to be arbitrary. A simple example should suffice to convince you. Let $f(x) =0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) =1$ when $x$ is irrational and consider this function on interval $[0,1]$. If we fix the partitioning scheme to consider only uniform partitions (sub-intervals are all of equal length) and the tagging scheme is fixed to choose left-hand end-points of the sub-intervals of the partition then we can easily see that the Riemann sum is $0$ and therefore its limit is also $0$. But as can be easily seen the function is not Riemann integrable as every upper Darboux is $1$ and every lower Darboux sum is $0$.

On the other hand keeping one of schemes fixed and the other one arbitrary is sufficient to show that the function is Riemann integrable. But the proof of this is difficult (especially the part where sampling scheme is fixed).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Think about refinements.

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of using a common refinement between 2 partitions (the one we know the limit exists, and some other one)? Though you'd still need to prove any refinement is independent of "refinement choice" :P

Answer (score 0):

Each partition consists of Intervals $I_j$ where $j \in \mathbb{N}$ for some finite amount of intervals. It suffices to prove that splitting one interval up into two intervals by adding a point makes the resulting Riemann integral more or equally precise.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient to prove what I'm asking

Comment: You are right I apologize, although it would be sufficient if your partitioning scheme's maximal interval length converges to 0.

Comment: I don't think so. I think need to start somewhere along the lines of showing that for any function that is Riemann-integrable over a range, then there exists a partitioning $[x_i]$ such that $x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}) \implies f(x) \in [f(x_i), f(x_{i+1}))$